# GPIO Permission issue Nvidia Jetson AGX Xavier

Tags: gpio, pwm, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

Good afternoon everyone,

When trying to control a stepper motor through the GPIO header on the AGX Xavier I ran into the following issue:

When utilizing the jetson-gpio library for python compatible GPIO control I am able to run all sample scripts (including the ‘simple_pwm.py’, this is relevant later in this post).

However, when I attempt to use the JetsonGPIO librari for c++ compatible GPIO control the following error appears when using the GPIO::PWM() command:

[image: Output]

The same command in Python (syntax) does work however. I have moved the 99-gpio.rules file to /etc/udev/rules.d and created the gpio group and added my user to this group. I have tried running all commands with sudo, with no effect unfortunately.

Does anyone know how to solve the permission issue? I would really like to use the GPIO::PWM function in a C++ script rather than python.

Best regards,

Ruud

Extra info:

As explained in the following link: [Configure GPIO Nvidia Jetson](https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/l4t/index.html#page/Tegra%20Linux%20Driver%20Package%20Development%20Guide/hw_setup_jetson_io.html)

The GPIO header of a Jetson device can be configured. The 3 PWM pins on the 40-pin expansion header are disabled by default so these needed to be enabled. I have done this.

Comment: Can you use `libgpiod` C++ bindings directly?

Comment: I am trying to use the jetsonGPIO library, not the libgpiod.